# Have following example of database design a name?

Tags: database, database-design

I am working with a customer that uses this kind of table name:

mod42_tabname

and for field names:

mod42_fieldname

and for foreign key I can see:

mod32_tab54_field_fk18

Does this pattern have a name?

Are there principles violated here?

Are there some suggestion to push customer to use simple and better to remember names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my personal experience, I would not speak of patterns or principles, but of nomenclature conventions combined with best practices; then these conventions are personal or business choices. The important thing is that the conventions adopted are kept within the project.
For example, I prefer to create tables with singular names (as the names od classes in the OOP are singular), while others use plural names.

This is a [style guide](https://medium.com/southprojects/database-naming-convention-the-definitive-guide-90424d6c2d36) about elements to name and the main conventions adopted.

Another method used, as in your case, is to group the tables, if the application is organized in independent modules and you do not want to use different databases.
I prefer to use different databases, but if this is not possible, this solution is often used.

As for the use of the prefix also in the name of fields, I find it very redundant because I have information already present in the table name.

As for your client's convention, is it applied to an existing application or is it still being evaluated?

In the first case, I see the change difficult because with time you will find a database with elements named differently.
In the second case, I would look for a less redundant and more speaking convention